# what does slot_1 slot_2 slot_3 mean in intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, concurrency, ide

[image]

I am debugging java by idea, but I do not know meaning of these gray hints.
what's special means of slot_2,3?
why there is no slot_1?

Comment: I would guess it refers to the stack indexes of those local variables that they take currently on the stack.

Comment: Assuming that “slot” refers to the local variable index in the current stack frame, `this` has the index zero and the parameter `releases` has the index one. That’s why it continues with index two for the first declared local variable. But these numbers where assigned by the compiler when this source code was converted to bytecode. It could have used other strategies for assigning the indices. Only the indices for `this` and the method’s parameters at method entry are predefined.

Comment: thank, it makes sense @Holger